# asp.net mvc json result format

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, format, jsonresult

```
public class JsonCategoriesDisplay
    {
        public JsonCategoriesDisplay() { }

        public int CategoryID { set; get; }
        public string CategoryTitle { set; get; }
    }

    public class ArticleCategoryRepository
    {
        private DB db = new DB();  

        public IQueryable<JsonCategoriesDisplay> JsonFindAllCategories()
        {
            var result = from c in db.ArticleCategories                         
                         select new JsonCategoriesDisplay
                         {
                             CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                             CategoryTitle = c.Title                            
                         };

            return result;
        }

          ....
    }

public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        ArticleRepository articleRepository = new ArticleRepository();
        ArticleCategoryRepository articleCategoryRepository = new ArticleCategoryRepository();


        public string Categories()
        {
            var jsonCats = articleCategoryRepository.JsonFindAllCategories().ToList();

            //return Json(jsonCats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { jsonCats});
        }

    }
```

This results with following:

```
{"jsonCats":[{"CategoryID":2,"CategoryTitle":"Politika"},{"CategoryID":3,"CategoryTitle":"Informatika"},{"CategoryID":4,"CategoryTitle":"Nova
kategorija"},{"CategoryID":5,"CategoryTitle":"Testna
kategorija"}]}
```

If I use line that is commented and place JsonResult instead of returning string, I get following result:<

```
[{"CategoryID":2,"CategoryTitle":"Politika"},{"CategoryID":3,"CategoryTitle":"Informatika"},{"CategoryID":4,"CategoryTitle":"Nova
kategorija"},{"CategoryID":5,"CategoryTitle":"Testna
kategorija"}]
```

But, I need result to be formatted like this:

```
{'2':'Politika','3':'Informatika','4':'Nova
kateorija','5':'Testna kategorija'}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this or I will need to hardcode result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Json.Net library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

> The Json.NET library makes working
>   with JavaScript and JSON formatted
>   data in .NET simple. Quickly read and
>   write JSON using the JsonReader and
>   JsonWriter or serialize your .NET
>   objects with a single method call
>   using the JsonSerializer.

I have successfully used it within a .net mvc project.

Comment: thank you for comment, but I think it will be, for my case, more simple to manually format result

Comment: Rippo, for who is this comment attended to?

Answer (score 2):

ile,

you really should look at the json.net lib, i was in a similar dilemma recently with json/jquery and mvc and tried my own hand-rolled version but hit the many limitations in my own implemetation. the newton json lib is quite simply a no-brainer - simple to use and always being updated. the current version works fantastically with nested structures, thus making that particular json formatting issue a non-issue.

give it a look, will take you 15 mins to get to grips with.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning it as an Array, Also if you return a JsonResult you can save alot of code (looks like you were attempting to get the formatting you wanted)

```
public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        ArticleRepository articleRepository = new ArticleRepository();
        ArticleCategoryRepository articleCategoryRepository = new ArticleCategoryRepository();

    public JsonResult Categories()
    {
        var jsonCats = articleCategoryRepository.JsonFindAllCategories().ToArray();

        return Json(jsonCats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

in my test I got a result of

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Cat 1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Cat 2"}]
```

Comment: thanks, but this result format is not what I need... I need only one pair of curly brackets.